# Ruby on rails - scaffolding generating files in another folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails. My folder structure is as below - 
[image]

1. todolists is my current project folder &
2. todolists-module1 was my previous project.

I executed scaffold through console -

[image]

As you can see, the files have been generated. However when I go to my current db/migrate folder I dont see any files -

[image]

But when I go to previous project file, I see the file has been generated there -

[image]

How do I make rails CLI to create files in my current project.

Comment: Try running `spring stop` from both the project directories, and then re-run the scaffold generator from the `todolists` project. It could be due to the spring loader issue.

Comment: @Dharam, thanks a lot. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `spring stop` from both the project directories, and then re-run the scaffold generator from the `todolists` project. It could be due to the spring loader issue.